# I have to get Lotus notes document by setting 2 combinations as unique

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, agent

I have to pick a document in lotus notes Using vertical and country as unique.
I have used below code which is showing error:

```
Set vcDoc = vcVw.GetDocumentByKey(empStubDoc.empVertical(0) & empStubDoc.empCountry(0))
```

My vertical form has following fields;

Vertical, Vertical Head, vertical HR SPOC, Country

Please let me know how can i do that if there is any alternative.

Comment: I would recommend not to use the extended notation, like you do. Best practice is to use GetItemValue() instead. There are several good reasons for it, among them performance (it is faster) and that if you have a field named the same as a document method or property (which could be added in a future version of Notes), your code will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the variable vcVw to refer to a view. The first view column of this view must contain the exact combination of the fields Vertical and Country and be sorted in order for you to be able to use GetDocumentByKey() with the values empStubDoc.empVertical(0) & empStubDoc.empCountry(0) as lookup key.

Comment: How to set the first column of VcVw..with excat combination of vertical and country?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, your form has the fields `Vertical`and `Country` then your code should be

```
cDoc = vcVw.GetDocumentByKey(empStubDoc.Vertical(0) & empStubDoc.Country(0), True)
```

Fieldnames have to be without starting "emp". You get the error because fields "empVertical" and "empCountry" not found in document.

Your view have to have a first sorted column with formula

```
Vertical + Country
```